# Typescript not accepting interface params

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In the following code the compiler is throwing error:

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 3.

Can anyone explain whats wrong and what needs to be changed? I have other interface based functions that are working fine, but this function doesnt seem to be acknowledging the interface properties.

Code:

```
interface withTitleComponentProps {
    component: Injectable<ReactElement> | ReactElement;
    title: string | null | undefined;
    isComponent?: boolean;
  }

export const withTitleComponent = (props: withTitleComponentProps): React.ComponentType => {
  let {component, title, isComponent} = props
  if (isComponent) {
    return titleComponent({
      NewComponent: withInjectedProps(component as Injectable<ReactElement>),
      title: title,
    });
  } else {
    return titleElement({
      NewComponent: component as ReactElement,
      title: title,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur

Comment: @youdateme When calling the function as: withTitleComponent( LandingScreen, null, true)

Comment: But why are you calling it with 3 arguments when you only specify 1 (`props`)...

Comment: You probably wanted to call it as `withTitleComponent( {LandingScreen, null, true}) `

Comment: @youdateme ive defined props like this before via interface without issue, i guess theres a misunderstanding on my side. Im trying to define the props in interface as props and types

Comment: @Chai calling like that creates error: Syntax error: ':' expected (66:20)

Comment: There is only one parameter `props` of type `withTitleComponentProps`, so you call it as `withTitleComponent({ component: LandingScreen, title: null, isComponent: true })`

Comment: @youdateme while this does work, id like to call to keep the call structure in tact rather than specifying a whole object, is there a way the interface/function could be modified to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment you say you are calling this function like:

```
withTitleComponent( LandingScreen, null, true)
```

However, you only declare that with one argument:

```
export const withTitleComponent = (props: withTitleComponentProps): React.ComponentType => {
```

Since `withTitleComponentProps` is a type that has properties, did you mean to pass in an object with those properties?

```
withTitleComponent({
  component: LandingScreen,
  title: null,
  isComponent: false,
})
```

---

Alternatively, declare it with three arguments:

```
export const withTitleComponent = (
  component: Injectable<ReactElement> | ReactElement;
  title: string | null | undefined;
  isComponent?: boolean;
): React.ComponentType => {}

withTitleComponent(LandingScreen, null, true)
```

---

Or use a tuple (as suggested by @youdateme)

```
type withTitleComponentProps = [
    component: Injectable<ReactElement> | ReactElement,
    title: string | null | undefined,
    isComponent?: boolean,
]

export const withTitleComponent = (...args: withTitleComponentProps): React.ComponentType => {}

withTitleComponent(LandingScreen, null, true) // works
```

Just note that this is *not* an object with 3 properties. It is a fixed length array with three element.

Comment: this fails with error: Syntax error: ':' expected (66:20)

Comment: While your updated answer works, id like to call to keep the call structure in tact rather than specifying a whole object, is there a way the interface/function could be modified to do this?

Comment: Per your update -> yes this is how i did it before, but id like to abstract the property definitions into an interface, is this not possible?

Comment: Use a tuple type `[component: ..., title: ..., isComponent?: ...]` and then in the function define it as `(...args: MyTupleType) => ...`

Comment: @youdateme could you provide an example please?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include that option.

Answer (score 1):

> Use a tuple type `[component: ..., title: ..., isComponent?: ...]` and then in the function define it as `(...args: MyTupleType) => ...`

Example:

```
type WithComponentTitleProps = [
    component: Injectable<ReactElement> | ReactElement,
    title: string | null | undefined,
    isComponent?: boolean,
];

const withComponentTitle = (...args: WithComponentTitleProps) => ...
```

Then you can reuse the type anytime you wish to have the same parameters as `withComponentTitle`

Comment: how would you access the args within the function? They are reporting "cannot find" on each

Comment: Destructure them with `const [component, title, isComponent] = args;`?

Comment: thank you, it is working as expected now!